# how i code the SplashScreenActivity.kt cuz mine doesn't work

Tags: android, kotlin, splash-screen

i want to add a splash screen to my app so i created an activity with a name of SplashScreen
and i add this code to the SplashScreenActivity.kt
but the android studio doesnt reconize java in
val i = Intent(this@MainActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
and it shown as red
Note that i use kotlin

```
package com.example.textnav

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity


class SplashScreen : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000L

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen)


                Handler().postDelayed(
                    {
                        val i = Intent(this@MainActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                        
                        startActivity(i)
                        finish()
                    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT
                )
            }
        }
```

[the pic](https://ibb.co/bmjVHNV)

the mainactivity.kt

```
package com.example.textnav

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

Comment: if you're going to show a splash activity and do nothing useful in it, consider just removing it. just showing a screen for X amount of time for no purpose isn't useful in your app

Comment: further than that, i don't know why you have the same class inside... itself ? why do you have two `class SplashScreen...` statements inside the same file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Handler().postDelayed(
    {
        val i = Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(i)
        finish()
    }, 
    SPLASH_TIME_OUT
)
```

`this` refers to the `{ }` lambda that you are inside (which is a `Runnable`).

Try:

`val i = Intent(this@SplashScreen, MainActivity::class.java)`

to get the `this` from an outer scope (your activity).

The Intent constructor you called expects a `Context` as its first parameter.
Your `this` is of the type `Runnable`.
With `this@SplashScreen` you are using the type `Activity` (which is a `Context`).

Comment: it doesnt work look again to the question i fix it

Comment: Your Activity is called `SplashScreen` not `MainActivity`, so replace that word. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: sorry if i disturb you but the word java still colored with red

Comment: You need to find the error message, to see what it is saying is the problem.

Comment: unresolved referece java [link](https://ibb.co/cJcGWqY)

Comment: and can I see the contents of the MainActivity.kt file pls?

Comment: its at the end of the question,, i update the question

Comment: not sure tbh! Maybe do a clean and a rebuild, see if it goes away